# How to identify which Chrome/Chromium tab is using up CPU?

Tags: google-chrome, cpu-load

I sometimes have a bunch of tabs opened in Google Chrome, which I believe creates a new process per tab. I would like to be able to identify the tab that is using up the CPU.

Is there an easy way to to that?

Comment: You can check which tab uses how much CPU from within Chrome. Click the wrench then in Background processes

Comment: For MacOS, click on the three dots in the **top right** of chrome browser [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR9bi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR9bi.png) Then click "More Tools" -> "Task Manager" You can then sort by Memory footprint or CPU [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ba1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ba1.png)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> on Windows or Linux, will bring up the Chrome Task Manager with a row for each tab - you can sort by Memory, CPU and a couple of other columns.

Alternatively on all OSes, you can find it through: Menu button → Tools → Task Manager.

Comment: By default, Shift + Esc doesn't appear to work, at least on a Mac it didn't. Menu, More Tools, and Task Manager worked a treat.

Comment: There isn't a keyboard shortcut on Chrome OSX but, you can find it under the Window menu next to Download and a Extensions

Comment: Is this still working? I only see one process "Browser", not a row for every tab. So I have "Browser" and some extensions I have installed but that doesn't help to identify the tab which cooks my CPU.

Comment: @udondan Works for me on 14.04. I do see a task called *Browser*, but I also see tasks for each individual tab.

Comment: None of these options exist anymore.

Comment: @rolls They do certainly in the current Chromium 53.0.2785.143 – which browser and which version were you trying?

Comment: On OSX with chrome  57.0.2987.133 (and it has been like this for a while), it only shows non-zero CPU on the broser table entry, which is of not much help.

Comment: Ironic:  the tab using the most CPU is the tab hosting this askubunu.com question. Chrome 67 on Windows 10.

Comment: Mac: Menu -> Window -> Task Manager

Comment: @rolls and others who have doubts: Shift+F10 is still working on Windows, just be sure you are staying in Chrome when you press Shift+F10. But! If you trying to find which tab is using CPU you don't have to find it here. If you see in Chrome Task Manager low CPU but in Windows Task Manager high CPU then Google's **Software Reporting Tool** is causing all your troubles. This "tool" is acting like a virus. Remove it from your PC.

Comment: @mojmir.novak it seems shift + escape works these days, that was 3 years ago I posted that comment.

Comment: @rolls I know. I just needed it now so it is info for all users incoming now. :-)

Comment: Any way to view this output from the command-line so I can log it? I added a question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686928/command-line-command-to-see-cpu-usage-of-chrome-tab-as-shown-in-chrome-task-man

Answer (score 1):

Chrome also has a more detailed task manager that can be accessed by right click in the title bar and select "Task Manager" (or Shift-ESC). You can see which tabs or extensions are using the most CPU or the most memory and switch too them.