# htop or Chrome task manager: Who lies?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Via `htop`, I noticed that Chrome is using 100% of a CPU.

[image]

I would like to find out what process in chrome uses that much CPU. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89568/how-to-identify-which-chrome-chromium-tab-is-using-up-cpu#:%7E:text=Pressing%20Shift%20%2B%20Esc%20on%20Windows,%E2%86%92%20Tools%20%E2%86%92%20Task%20Manager.) suggests using SHIFT+Esc to open the task mananger. There, however, I find nothing of significance:

[image]

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

For sure your `top`/`htop` doesn't lie, but Chrome is a multi-process/multi-thread application. One process per window and per tab, one for each extension, one for the GPU. Just try `ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -i chrome` .

The other point is about *timing*. The time it takes you from a terminal to the web UI of chrome can make the difference. You'd be keeping open both the terminal with `htop` **and** the Task manager at the same time.